# Print String based on certain constraints in Java (Strings and Arrays) (Compress Decompress)

Tags: java, arrays, string

We can assume that the constraint is an Integer that was converted to a String to a character array. I am having trouble on how to solve this.

```
 Construct a string with given constraints:
input: abcd
const: 123
o/p: abbcccd

input: abcde
const: 4
o/p: aaaabcde
```

also decode in the same manner

eg:
    i/p: aabbbccccd
    const:2341
    o/p: abcd

This is what I wrote but I am sure my second loop logic is incorrect

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String input = "abcd";
    String output = "";
    int arr[] = null;
    int constraint = 123;

    char[] s = Integer.toString(constraint).toCharArray();
    int min_val = Math.min(s.length, input.length());
    for(int i=0; i < min_val; i++)
    {

        for(int j = 0; j < s[i]; j++ )
        {
            output=output+input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: What have you done to solve this? What didn't work and why? Which errors did you encounter? where is your code?

Comment: If you have tried anything then please mention here. You can't expect someone to answer the whole question for you.

Comment: I have added what I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ::

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s="abcd";
        int num=2341;
        String num1=Integer.toString(num);
        String[] nums=num1.split("");
        String result="";

        for(int i=1;i<nums.length;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);j++){
                result=result+s.charAt(i-1);
            }
        }   
        System.out.println(result);     
    }
```

Output::

```
aabbbccccd
```